# jump to another page in word with visual basic

Tags: vba, word-2003

I am working with visual basic now for the first time in word 2003.
I want to know if there is a way to jump to another pagenumber.

I have a checkbox and if that checkbox is true it has to redirect me to let say pagenumber 5. I know how to find out if a checkbox is true, but i can't figure out the jump to pagenumber 5 part.

Can somebody please help me with this one?

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Might be worth downloading this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15400

Comment: it sure is usefull! Thanks for this post, but I can't find the answer to my question in this help file. Is it in there and am I just simply overlooking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this snippet of code:

```
Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 5 'your page number here
```